# Ploting a line graph with ggplot

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I have a csv file with dates and values, the dates are formated such as 20150612.
I want to plot a line graph which represent changes over time. The values should be on the Y axis and date on X.

What I have so far is:

`data <- read.csv("commit.csv")
days <- as.Date(as.character(data$Day), "%Y%m%d")
change <- (data$Commit)`

As you can see I managed to convert the dates so now I get 2015-06-12 instead, which allows me to use scale_x_date so I can present the date as year/month. How do I do the rest?

The data looks like this:

20150607,4.10014657
...and so on, around 2000 rows.

Comment: You should add a view lines from you csv file. That way it is easier to help you.

Comment: this question has been answered several time before. Please just search SO

Answer (score 4):

Would this help?

Random example

```
sDate <- as.Date("20150603", format="%Y%m%d") #Start date
intervals <- seq(sDate,by="days", length.out=30) #Create a random time series
data <- 10 + runif(30, -1,2)

timeSeries <- zoo(data.frame(data=data),intervals) #Create a zoo class timeseries

ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x=Index,y=data))+ #x axis and y axis 
  geom_line(color="red", size=2, alpha=0.2) # Control color, size of line and opacity
```

[image: ggplot example for line plot]